# LatLngBounds vs LatLng

Tags: google-maps

Working a bit with the Google Maps API and a bit confused as to what exactly the difference between these two is. Why can't I use the same coordinates for LatLngBounds as I did with LatLng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different things.  A LatLng is a geographic point.  A LatLngBounds is a rectangular area defined by two points (the southwest and northeast corners).

[google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

> A LatLng is a point in geographical coordinates: latitude and longitude.

[google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

> A LatLngBounds instance represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates, including one that crosses the 180 degrees longitudinal meridian.